# Google data studio community connector local development tool returns "getSystemErrorName is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, looker-studio

I'm following this [Google data connector's local development](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/local-development) resource to create a new community-connector. But when I run `npx @google/dscc-gen connector` command I get `getSystemErrorName is not a function` error. I'm stuck to it. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `node` solved the issue!
Calling `util.getSystemErrorName` was causing the error, according to [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_getsystemerrorname_err) `util.getSystemErrorName` added in Node v9.7.0 .

To update Node you can follow these steps:

`sudo npm install -g n` (install n)

`sudo n latest`

For a specific version use this: `sudo n 8.9.0`